# how to call data in ajax with dynamic arrays

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I need to call some data after clicking on an `<option name="xxx">` in a `<select>` in index.php.

The data that I need to call are stored in some dynamic arrays in a different page (select.php)

I have created some arrays in this way in select.php page

```
${$team} = array();
```

The string contained in $team that names the array is exactly the value and the name of each of my select options.

So for instance I have`<option value="jack">jack</option>` in index.php and I have in select.php:

```
$team = "jack";
${$team} = ("name1", "name2", "name3");
```

(of course my explanation is simplified or I would create directly the $jack = array(); :-)!

I tried in this way but it doesn't seem to work:

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillSelect(){
            var $select = $('#sub_category'); 
            $select.find('option').remove(); 
            if($('#root_category').val() != '#'){
                $.getJSON( 'select.php', {
                    root_category: $('#root_category').val()
                    }
                )
                .done(function( data ) {
                    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
<form name="module" id="idModule" method="post" action="action.php">
     Chose team:
        <select name="root_category" id="root_category" onChange="fillSelect();">
            <option value="#">Selezionare</option>
            <option value="jack">jack</option></select>

        Here I want to show results<select name="sub_category" id="sub_category"></select>
    </form>
```

and in select.php

```
json_encode(${$_GET['root_category']});
```

Comment: This is not the way to store data in php. You should use a database, a text file or even a php file with arrays with meaningful keys and sub-arrays. In case you didn't realize, the value in an array can be an array as well.

Comment: of course I store data in php and this data is sorted into some arrays

Comment: I copied your code and everything works fine here. Did you see some error in your log file? What select.php does?